# rest framework django "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am using django rest framework. am getting error `"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."` i also trying two ways but error is still there. can anybody know how can i solve this error.

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Book


class BookSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'price']
```

views.py 1

```
class BookCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerialzer
```

OR: i am trying two ways for solving this issue but error is still there

views.py 2

```
class BookCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = BookSerialzer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BookCreateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', BookCreateView.as_view()),
   # path('create/', BookCreateView.as_view(), name='create-repo') /// same error with that
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`ListCreateAPIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) instead of `CreateAPIView`

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView


class BookCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerialzer
```

Comment: your code provide  create and list api. i just want a create api and i want to render my own template. my question is updated now pls review...

Comment: Please do ask a new question since the OP is answerd